# .net Core for Windows application using Visual studio 2015?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, .net-core

I have read a lot of articles about asp.net 5 (.net core) which provides a cross site platform compiler. I want know to is it possible to develop a ASP.NET 5 service App Using Visual Studio 2015 to record the session time of all devices connected to my network which include mac os, linux os, & windows os?

Detailed Explanation.

Suppose I build a WCF service 'SessionTimer' in VS2015 which record all the session timings and successfully installed in all the windows os of my network. I need to install the same in other system having mac os and linux os. If I install dotnet core in these machines, am I able to run 'SessionTimer' in these devices too??

Any help by giving supporting articles or points?

Comment: Check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386063.aspx)

Comment: What is your definition of desktop apps? .NET Core 1.0 will only enable console and web apps. Gui apps are delayed to a future release based on requests and technical feasibility (that's something unclear right now).

Comment: @LexLi I mean a service application like, I want to record all the session time in my network which have windows os, mac os and linux os, Is it able to write a service application in VS2015 and run it in all the devices?

Comment: @Russell session time is another thing that's ambiguous here. You need to define it properly and update the question.

Comment: @LexLi, Question edited, please check

Comment: @Russell then it becomes what API might help you analyze sessions on non-Windows platforms. There is no built in support (even on Windows) so that you will have to PInvoke and find the native APIs.

Answer (score -3):

Look into Docker for such needs https://www.docker.com/what-docker

Comment: Please understand the question and answer